# Why is my front-end call to my back-end service being refused?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, request

I have an Angular 4 application running on the port 8001 of an IIS server, that should access two back-end .NET APIs running on the same server, one on the port 89 and another on the port 83.

This application is being accessed by two kinds of users: some that are on the same network as the application server and some that are accessing through a virtual IP that has permission to acess the port 8001 of that server, and just that port.

The front-end calls the APIs using REST, with code like this:

```
this.http.post<boolean>(`http://<ServerHostname>:89/api/Controller/VerifyLogin`, body);
```

When testing with users on the same network, the call pass and everything works as expected. When testing with users accessing through the virtual IP, they are able to get to the front-end application, the front-end shows up but the calls to the API do not work. It might be because the request is being made using the server hostname instead of 'localhost' but I am not sure about that.

I tried to change the call to the API to use localhost, like this:

```
this.http.post<boolean>(`http://localhost:89/api/Controller/VerifyLogin`, body);
```

but when I test it on the same network, the API request does not complete.

This is the error message that appear on the Chrome console: 

`zone.js:2933 OPTIONS http://localhost:89/api/GravacaoDb/VerificarLogin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

**EDIT**:
Here is the CORS configuration inside my Web.config file in the API:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="86400" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

What can be the problem with what am I doing? What can be the reason the request is not allowed?

Comment: CORS is the usual reason. In this case it may be because you've not set up your Web API to allow OPTIONS headers. There are a number of posts about that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Try to hit the same URL using POSTMAN first and check your services are running smoothly or not. Timeout could be a reason for that

Comment: In any case, you'll need to do a bit more debugging on your side (look at your service's logs, configuration, etc.).

Comment: @HereticMonkey. I have the CORS options enabled on my application. It is setup inside my Web.config file. I had CORS problem earlier while building the project and setting it up solve it

Comment: Show that configuration.

Comment: @HereticMonkey. Thanks for the help. Just edited the configuration on the question.

Comment: @SRana, I did a test with POSTMAN just now and the service returns normally.

Comment: This is not a CORS problem. The error message means that a firewall restricts access. You need to configure the network such that users with the virtual IP are allowed to access port 89 of your server or (if that is not possible) create some proxy service that listens on port 8001 and forwards requests to port 89.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand that the Angular code runs in the browser of the user, not on the server where it is stored. So, the API calls that you make come from the user's browser. If that browser is outside your local network, firewalls will block access (as you say yourself in the question)

Comment: Did you specifically make a request with the OPTIONS method using Postman?

Comment: Did you do the test using Postman from inside your local network or from outside the network?

Comment: @David I did not do a specific test on POSTMAN with OPTIONS, but the OPTIONS request from the browser are passing, if the user is inside the network.

Comment: @NineBerry I did a test with POST, from a computer that can reach the network and it passed

Comment: @CaioTsubake from a computer going through the same "virtual ip" or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not consider that the Angular code runs in the browser of the user, not on the server where it is stored. So, the API calls that you make come from the user's browser. If that browser is outside your local network, firewalls will block access via any other port than 8001 (as you say yourself in the question).

So, this is not a CORS problem.

You need to configure the network firewall such that users with the virtual IP are allowed to access port 89 of your server or (if that is not possible) create some proxy service that listens on port 8001 (or some other port allowed in the firewall) and forwards requests to port 89.

---

One important thing to consider:

If you open access to your APIs this way, then anyone can call these APIs unchecked. But this is a general problem. Allowing API access from client-side JavaScript code means that anyone call call these APIs.

Comment: I have a question: in the case were its not possible to allow access to other ports, can the proxy service be hosted on port 8001 together with the Angular app?
Also, I see  what you mean by anyone being able to call my API being a problem. Is there another way to make a request from Angular so that the request is made by the server?

Comment: Your current solution seems to be a Single Page Application where all the business logic resides in the JavaScript code in the client. It is a known weakness of such a scenario that you cannot enforce business rules this way. You would have to change the architecture of the application to have the business rules on the server, not in the client.

Comment: The alternative (if the only rules you need to enforce are who is allowed to do what) is to use shared authentication between all the involved APIs so that each API can check whether the person making the call is allowed to or not

Comment: That is weird. I had understood that my business logic was on the APIs side, not on the JS code. Take the login method from the question: the user types the login and password, this gets send to the API on the port 89 through  the body, the API authenticates that user and returns True or False depending on the result. The client only sends the data and gets the result.
 Is that not the way to have the logic on the server?